# Forcing Windows updates to pop-up during a presentation

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I am giving a presentation about Microsoft/Windows updates. To get the attention of the public I want this screen to pop-up in the middle of my presentation; maybe with a shortcut.

[image: Windows update pop-up]

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Comment: Why don't you just use a screenshot within your presentation?

Comment: Any reason you cannot add that image to your presentation to show at the desired time?

Comment: @Ramhound it would be more cooler if it was a real windows update and I could click the remind me in 4 hours postpone

Comment: Unless you actually have an update pending, there is no way, to bring that notification up.

Comment: I do you the update pending on my system :D. I thought maaaaybe there is some kind of program for this.