# How to create a shortcut to Windows Update?

Tags: windows-update, shortcuts, file-shortcut

I know how to create a shortcut to the configuration screen of Windows Update with this command:

```
%windir%\System32\rundll32.exe url.dll,FileProtocolHandler wuapp.exe
```

[image]

However is there any way to specifically open this window?

[image]

If so, how?

Comment: [Why are you asking the same question a different way?](http://superuser.com/questions/979200/forcing-windows-updates-to-pop-up-during-a-presentation?noredirect=1#comment1345262_979200)

Comment: @Ramhound because i feel like i have more and new information about the subject now

Comment: if you feel you have more information to add, please edit your existing question and update it, instead of repeating the same question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper command for that would be:

`%windir%\system32\wuapp.exe startmenu`

Comment: this still opened the same

Comment: Since you modified your question, no, it doesn't anymore. Now that your question is modified, YES, it is a duplicate.

Comment: I mean the command it still opens the first picture, instead of the second one

Comment: I know, but you were asking for that before, or at least that's what I understood. I don't think you can do what you want, anyways.

Comment: so the answer is that it isnt possible? :)

Comment: Yeah, think so.